# How to set SSRS tablix cell border color with an expression?

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, reportingservices-2005

I'm using

```
=IIF(IsNothing(ReportItems!GradeLevel),"White","LightGrey")
```

in the Color function box, I click NONE, then click each border to apply the border color, save, execute and border doesn't change.

[image: areas of interest]

When I go back to the properties, it's been reset to *LightGrey*

[image: boring reversion]

Not the end of the world, but mildly annoying.

Comment: try `=IIF(IsNothing(ReportItems!GradeLevel.Value),"White","LightGrey")`

Comment: Also, if you set no border, it does not matter what colour you choose. You probably need to set the border to outline.

Comment: @AlanSchofield is is set to outline, as you can see from the screen shot.  I'll try adding the .Value.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the none/outline preset. Did the Expression I suggested work?